Emf in stationary conductor located in a uniform magnetic field, when the source of this field moves relative to the conductor
When a conductor moves with velocity $\vec v$ in a uniform magnetic field $\vec B$ produced by a stationary source, then the magnetic force in this conductor push charges from one end of the conductor to the other.

But if we have the opposite situation: the conductor is stationary and located in a uniform magnetic field $\vec B$ “moving” to the conductor with velocity $\vec v$ (directed to the left), then we’ll see the same.

What a force pushes charges this time?
I guess It is a force that come from induced electric field $\vec E^*$. This field is caused by changing magnetic field:

But if we take a close path within the conductor and use the last expression we’ll get 0 for the right side of this expression, because the magnetic flux doesn’t change for any such a path. So, $\vec E^*$ has to be 0 too. Where I am wrong, or how can last formula be used the to explain the charge separation in the conductor in terms of forces?
Thanks in advance.
P.S. This situation is considered in textbook «Principles and practice of Physics” by Eric Mazur (first edition p. 781), but there is no real explanation there.
UPDATE
I guess I’ve found the answer in a textbook “Physics for Scientists and Engineers” by Randall D. Knight (p. 900). The main idea is that the second picture is incorrect, because it does not include the electric field, which is observed when the source of magnetic field moves.
Here are some screens on that (from the textbook):


Thanks everyone for trying to help!

First of all, the magnetic field is not changing inside the conductor, because it is constant in magnitude and direction inside it, throught the motion you considered.
For analysing this case, you can think of this case by taking the object and observer to be moving with speed v towards right. This would mean that from the frame of the observer, the object will be at rest and the field moving to left.
Now, you can switch to a frame in which the object moves to the right and the field is at rest and find the results.

I know that we can just move to other reference frame (actually the pictures here are just about that), but I guess there should be explanation for any reference frame. My question is about the case when the rod is motionless.
